# Form submission open new tab in Chrome though work fine in Firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

i have button with name send

here is my javascript to submit the button

```
  $("[name='create']").click(function(event) {
      alert("12");
      var form = $("[name='form']");
      form.submit(); 
      window.close();
  });
```

Chrome opens the new tab on form submission. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have added `target='_blank'` in your form. Even if not try adding `target='_self'` in your form and check.